# How to check a server's power status using ipmiutil?

Tags: ipmi

I look at the [ipmiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/) document,

but I do not find a command to show the Server's power status.

Who can tell me how to check a server's power status?

---

**EDIT-01**

I use my `ipmiutil` command check my server status, I see the `Chassis Status    = 10 00 00 ff`, what's the meaning of the number?

```
[dele@localhost ~]$ ipmiutil health -N 172.18.16.230 -U ADMIN -P ADMIN
ipmiutil health ver 3.13
BMC manufacturer  = 000000 ( ), product = 0000 
BMC version       = 6.00, IPMI v5.4
IPMI driver type  = 6        (lan)
Power State       = 01       (S1: clock stopped, context ok)
Selftest status   = 0010     (Error), last = 0010
Chassis Status    = 10 00 00 ff (off, see below)
    chassis_power       = off, control error
    pwr_restore_policy  = stay_off
    chassis_intrusion   = inactive
    front_panel_lockout = inactive
    drive_fault         = false
    cooling_fan_fault   = false
    FP sleep_button_disable = allowed, button disabled
    FP diag_button_disable  = allowed, button disabled
    FP reset_button_disable = allowed, button disabled
    FP power_button_disable = allowed, button disabled



BMC LAN Channels  = 
Chan 1 AuthTypes  = MD2 MD5 Straight_Passwd 
ipmiutil health, completed successfully
```

Comment: Why simply ping?

Comment: BMC will not down.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a health check:

ipmiutil health -N ipaddress -U user -P password

Comment: thanks your response, can you take a look at my EDIT?